# How to prevent app data stolen after device rooting

Tags: android, security, rooted-device

I've received a requirement from customer that if device is getting rooted after app has been used, then clear all cache and app db.
Though we can handle once app started but is it possible to handling without opening our app? 
Suppose below is the case -

> I've XYZ app installed and some persisted data & client db related to my app is stored in app cache. 
>   Now someone rooted the android device  and try to fetch all stored db and persisted data.

Is it possible to prevent such case?

Comment: Only by not storing data on the device in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get the statement "in the first place"? Is this any new technique or you simply saying to not store any concerning data in app cache?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you don't want users to get at the data, don't store it on the device ! Instead, store it on a server, and fetch it (over the internet) as needed.

Comment: I am simply saying to not store any data in the device. It is the user's device. The data either came from the user (e.g., direct entry into the app) or was downloaded by the user. Hence, it is the user's data, and the user can choose to do whatever the user wants with that data.

Comment: Very clear explanation :)

Comment: I know that people don't suggest to doing it but is it not possible to set a onReboot() broadcast and place a check in app for rooted device and clear all persisted data in app cache? Don't mind..asking due to just a thought :)

Comment: Yes, you could do that - however, the user will be able to set the device to not start your app (quite easy), and thus your `onReboot()` listener will not be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is not saving anything you want to protect on the device - save it on your app server and send it to your app. App never write it to the device, just use it in its memory.

If you using a lot of data and you don't want to send it every time or it's too much to handle in memory, you can save it encrypted on the device and store the key in app server.

Note that both options are not fully protect your data, just make it more difficult to a malicious user to get it.